# Fix Device driver API match - Device driver API version: 23

Tags: android-studio, widget, android-5.0-lollipop

**Error:**

```
4761-4779/com.android.widgets E/﹕ Device driver API match
    Device driver API version: 23
    User space API version: 23
4761-4779/com.android.widgets E/﹕ mali: REVISION=Linux-r3p2-01rel3 BUILD_DATE=Wed Oct  9 21:05:57 KST 2013
```

**Devices:**

```
Samsung Galaxy N7000 XXLT9
Recovery: Rooted, PhilZ-cwm6-XXLT9-ORA-5.08.5
Rom: Nightowl-cm12.1-Beta4-n7000
Android: Lollipop 5.1.1
Kernel (Not touched): 3.0.64-Bauner-g8d135b8-dirty bauner@pc #1

Microsoft Surface Pro
Windows 8.1
```

**Tool:**

```
Android Studio 1.1.0
```

**build.gradle:**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 12
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.commonsware.android.appwidget.lorem"
        minSdkVersion 11
        targetSdkVersion 11
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}
```

**Screenshot:**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/kaWSH.png

**Problem:**
I can't use the device for development. I don't know why. Other apps (like [LoremWidget](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/AppWidget/LoremWidget)) are working on that device perfectly. And my app on my Oppo N1 is also working perfect! How to fix it and what cause this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okey I don't really fixed it for myself, but this only appears if you're using a **samsung device** with a **custom rom** based on cyanogenmod.

It's only an error if get `Device driver API mismatch`. Try to ignore it or use a different device. It's not influencing your app.

That's how I handle this error :) Hope it helped!